# Groupby and filter by max value in pandas

Tags: r, pandas, dataframe, filter

I am working on a dataframe that looks like the following: (ID 2 added in edit)

```
+-------+----+------+------+
| Value | ID | Date | ID 2 |
+-------+----+------+------+
|     1 |  5 | 2012 | 111 |
|     1 |  5 | 2013 | 112 |
|     0 | 12 | 2017 | 113 |
|     0 | 12 | 2022 | 114 |
|     1 | 27 | 2005 | 115 |
|     1 | 27 | 2011 | 116 |
+-------+----+------+-----+
```

Only using rows with "Value" == "1" ("value is boolean), I would like to group the dataframe by ID and input the string "latest" to new (blank) column, giving the following output:

```
+-------+----+------+--------+
| Value | ID | Date | Latest |
+-------+----+------+--------+
|     1 |  5 | 2012 |        |
|     1 |  5 | 2013 | Latest |
|     0 | 12 | 2017 |        |
|     0 | 12 | 2022 |        |
|     1 | 27 | 2005 |        |
|     1 | 27 | 2011 | Latest |
+-------+----+------+--------+
```

The syntax of pandas is throwing me off as I am fairly new to Python.

In R I suppose I would be trying something like

```
df %>% select(Value == "1") %>% group_by(ID) %>% select(max(Date)
```

but I am not sure of the syntax in Pandas...I am trying to first select the subset of rows that meets the criteria "value == 1" by using

```
q = df.query('Value == 1')
my_query_index = q.index
my_query_index
```

This returns the index of all the rows but I am not sure how to incorporate this into the dataframe before grouping and filtering by max(date).

All help appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT: I used the pinned answer as following:

```
latest = df.query('Value==1').groupby("ID").max("Year").assign(Latest = "Latest")
df = pd.merge(df,latest,how="outer")
df
```

But I have since realized some of the max years are the same, i.e. there could be 4 rows, all with max year 2017. For the tiebreaker, I need to use the max ID 2 within groups. I have added `.groupby("ID 2").max("ID 2")` to the line of code, giving

```
latest = df.query('Value==1').groupby("ID").max("Year").groupby("ID 2").max("ID 2").assign(Latest = "Latest")
df = pd.merge(df,latest,how="outer")
df
```

but it is giving me a dataframe completely different than the one desired.

Thank you for your help, all is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this:

```
latest = df.query('Value==1').groupby("ID").max("year").assign(Latest = "Latest")
pd.merge(df,latest,how="outer")

   Value  ID  Date  Latest
0      1   5  2012     NaN
1      1   5  2013  Latest
2      0  12  2017     NaN
3      0  12  2022     NaN
4      1  27  2005     NaN
5      1  27  2011  Latest
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Sort by `'ID'` then by `'Date'`
2. Use `duplicated(keep='last')` to identify the last item in each group
3. `loc` to assign in the right spot

---

```
df = df.sort_values(['ID', 'Date'])
mask1 = df.Value.eq(1)
mask2 = ~df.ID.duplicated(keep='last')

df.loc[mask1 & mask2, 'Latest'] = 'Latest'

df

   Value  ID  Date  Latest
0      1   5  2012     NaN
1      1   5  2013  Latest
2      0  12  2017     NaN
3      0  12  2022     NaN
4      1  27  2005     NaN
5      1  27  2011  Latest
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to groupby, using `transform` to get the max, then use a conditional statement with np.where to get the output:

```py
max_values = df.groupby("ID").Date.transform("max")
df.assign(Latest=np.where(df.Date.eq(max_values) & df.Value.eq(1), "Latest", ""))

   Value  ID  Date  Latest
0      1   5  2012        
1      1   5  2013  Latest
2      0  12  2017        
3      0  12  2022        
4      1  27  2005        
5      1  27  2011  Latest
```